# Meaning of Brackets in MD5 round definition in RFC 1321?

Tags: md5, notation, rfc

I'm trying to write a program that performs the MD5 hashing algorithm. I'm primarily using [RFC 1321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321) as a reference to write the program. In the rounds, it gives a series of calculations to be done each with a different format. *(This might not be the best explanation, but I don't think explaining this well is particularly important to my question.)* I have shown the format from round 1 as an example:

> a = b + ((a + F(b,c,d) + X[k] + T[i]) <<< s)

I'm not quite sure how to interpret the square brackets in the equation. *(That's the X[k].)* Earlier in the Terminology and Notation section it said that XY denotes the bit-wise and of X and Y; is that what that means? 
Or, is it like an array index and meant to get either a 1 or 0 from the number? 
Or, does it mean something it indicate something else? 
Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this question belongs on SO. My guess would be that this indicates the ith element in array T (or the kth element in array X).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little above that formula, you'll find this definition

> Let `T[i]` denote the `i-th` element of the table

So for the sake of consistency it's safe to assume that `X[k]` denotes the `k-th` element of `X`